# How to sort image blocks by to minimize the differences between them?

Tags: sorting, image-processing, language-agnostic

I have a list of small image blocks. All of them are the same size (eg : 16x16). They are black and white, with pixel values between 0-255. I would like to sort those images to minimize the the difference between them.

What I have in mind is to compute the [mean absolute difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_difference) (MAD) of pixels between adjacent blocks (eg : block N vs block N+1, block N+1 vs block N+2, ...). 
From this I can calculate the sum of those MAD values (eg : sum = mad1 + mad2 + ...). What I would like is to find the ordering that minimize that sum.

Before :

[image]

After : (this was done by hand only to provide an example, there is probably a better ordering for those blocks, especially the ones with vertical stripes)

[image]

Comment: It looks like a Travelling Salesman Problem, where each image is a city and the MAD between two images is the distance. It seems so impossible to resolve it in linear time.

Comment: Maybe i can approximate result by sorting blocks by their average luminance.

Comment: With the set of images presented above, it will probably do the job. In fact, unless the algorithm aims at processing any images set, the best way to do it is to use prior knowledge on images to restrict the research. Otherwise, it exists approximate algorithms to solve the problem in euclidean cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on *RaymoAisla* comment which pointed out this is similar to [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), I have decided to implement a solution using [Nearest neighbour algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_algorithm). While not perfect, it gives great results :

[image]

Here is code :

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def sortImages(images):  #Nearest neighbour algorithm
    result = []
    tovisit = range(len(images)) 

    best = max(tovisit, key=lambda x: images[x].sum()) #brightest block as first
    tovisit.remove(best)
    result.append(best)

    while tovisit: 
        best = min(tovisit, key=lambda x: MAD(images[x], images[best])) #nearest neighbour
        tovisit.remove(best)
        result.append(best)
    return result  #indices of sorted image blocks

def MAD(a, b): #mean absolute distance
    return np.absolute(a - b).sum()

images = ... #should contains b&w images only (eg : from PIL Image)
arrays = [np.array(x).astype(int) for x in images] #convert images to np arrays
result = sortImages(arrays)
```